# Wrong timezone in GridView yii2

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

Hello I have some trouble with timezone. My timeZone is Asia/Novosibirsk.

In index.php set timezone and yii formatter output:

```
\Yii::$app->formatter->timeZone // Asia/Novosibirsk
```

So in **yii\grid\GridView** winget I have the next columns of the same date (**date_add**):

```
            [
              'attribute' => 'date_add',
              'format' => ['date', 'full']
            ],
            'date_add:datetime',
            [
              'attribute' => 'date_add',
              'value' => function($row){
                return \Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime(new DateTime($row->date_add), 'full');
              }
            ],
```

Output different values:
[image]

Only third column is right, 14 December (raw date is *2016-12-14 17:00:00*).

I assume, that GridView have own timeZone (or formatter class instance)

Answer (score 1):

GridView is using `formatter` component (you can change it's settings in GridView or for the whole application in the application configuration) so just modify the time zone and everything should work properly.

For just the GridView settings:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    // ...
    'formatter' => [
        'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
        'timeZone' => 'Asia/Novosibirsk'
    ],
    // ...
]) ?>
```

For the whole application (configuration file like `config/web.php` in basic project template, settings for `formatter`):

```
return [
    // ...
    'components' => [
        // ...
        'formatter' => [
            'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
            'timeZone' => 'Asia/Novosibirsk'
        ],
    ],
];
```

or application wide:

```
return [
    // ...
    'timeZone' => 'Asia/Novosibirsk'
    // ...
];
```

Comment: I had already in main config property timeZone but it no has effect. \Yii::$app->formatter return the right timeZone

Comment: If I input formatter config **directly** in **GridView** it's too no has effect

Comment: Have you changed the `defaultTimeZone` in formatter component? What is the time zone of your database?

Comment: defaultTimeZone is UTC. But i assume that on MySQL server timeZone is GMT + 0

Comment: GMT+0 gives the same results as UTC. I guess your DB is in different timezone. Please double check it. When you use `DateTime` date is automatically converted to timezone of your system.